# RESTEasy java.lang.LinkageError: LinkageError while defining class: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher

Tags: web-services, resteasy, websphere-6.1

I am trying to implement RESTEasy in my project, which is giving

> java.lang.LinkageError: LinkageError while defining
>   class:org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher

I am using websphere 6.1 and RESTEasy 2.1.0.GA

The detail error is as follows:

> `Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: LinkageError while defining class: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
>   Could not be defined due to: (org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/server/servlet/HttpServletDispatcher) bad major version at offset=6
>   This is often caused by having a class defined at multiple
>   locations within the classloader hierarchy.  Other potential causes
>   include compiling against an older or newer version of the class
>   that has an incompatible method signature.
>   Dumping the current context classloader hierarchy:
>       ==> indicates defining classloader
>   ==>[0] 
>   com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@46204620
>      Local ClassPath: 
>      Delegation Mode: PARENT_FIRST
>      [1] 
>   com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@20ac20ac
>      Local ClassPath: 
>      Delegation Mode: PARENT_FIRST
>      [2] com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader@49de49de
>      [3] com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader@7b127b12
>      [4] org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@2db22db2
>      [5] sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@62e662e6
>      [6] sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@7fee7fee
>   ---Original exception---
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: (org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/server/servlet/HttpServletDispatcher) bad major version at offset=6
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:258)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
>       at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:555)
>       at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.findClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:506)
>       at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:380)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:597)
>       at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:202)
>       at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:63)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper$1.run(ServletWrapper.java:1334)
>       at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadServlet(ServletWrapper.java:1329)
>       at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadServlet(ServletWrapper.java:388)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:410)
>       at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3440)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:267)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:815)
>       at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1461)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:119)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:102)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:743)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:873)
>       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)

--- end Original exception----

```
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:602)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.findClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:506)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:597)
at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:202)
at java.beans.Beans.instantiate(Beans.java:63)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper$1.run(ServletWrapper.java:1334)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadServlet(ServletWrapper.java:1329)
... 19 more
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library you are attempting to use was compiled using Java 1.6. WebSphere Application Server 6.1 supports only 1.5.